# How to create a custom xp ComboBox from scratch in vb 6

Tags: vb6

Since a time like a few weeks ago, I have spent lots of time searching the web for a fully customized custom vb 6 xp user controls which I could use in an application of mine. I didn't find any good looking free ones. I don't pretend that there is no such control created. I managed to get some vb 6 projects on http://planet-source-code.com/ which have a number of custom user controls. Please if anyone can help me build one like a searchable combobox and xp theme I would appreciate.

Comment: There is a nice set of VB6 controls which you might consider, at this link: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?698563-CommonControls-(Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls)

Answer (score 0):

Use a manifest file, simple as that. You can create xp themes easy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
    <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">  
   <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" name="prjThemed" type="win32" />  
    <dependency>  
    <dependentAssembly>  
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" />  
    </dependentAssembly>  
    </dependency>  
</assembly>
```

it only works when you compile the exe, lets say the exe name is test.exe name the file test.exe.manifest.

Hope this helps!

Comment: doesnt look like a friendly answer to me

Comment: This is a ideal solution, many programs use manifest files and themes for their programs. I am pretty sure Microsoft office does it too!